# Permission Denied on SSH, but can VNC with same credentials

Tags: ssh, vnc, password

I have a raspberry pi on my network and have ssh'd into for over a year now nearly on a daily basis. I have VNC setup as well which I use about once a week.

Suddenly today I can no longer SSH in. I get "permission denied." But when I VNC with the same username and password I log in just fine.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to determine that my bin/bash file was missing. Not sure what happened but this is why I can't ssh but can use VNC.